# Why is Rtweet's parse_stream() function returning a NULL object?

Tags: r, json, rtweet

I have a series of .json files each containing data captured from between 500 and 10,000 tweets (3-40 MB each). I am trying to use rtweet's `parse_stream()` function to read these files into R and store the tweet data in a data table. I have tried the following:

```
tweets <- parse_stream(path = "india1_2019090713.json")
```

There is no error message and the command creates a `tweets` object, but it is empty (NULL). I have tried this with other .json files, and the result is the same. Has anyone encountered this behaviour/is there something obvious I am doing wrong? I would appreciate any advice to an rtweet newbie!

I am using rtweet version 0.6.9.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update and partial answer:
I've not made progress with the original issue, but I have had a lot more success using the jsonlite package, which is amply able to read in large and complex .json files containing Tweet data.

```
library(jsonlite)
```

I used the `fromJSON()` function as detailed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html). I found I needed to edit the original .json file to match the required structure, beginning and ending the file with square brackets ([ ]) and adding a comma before each line break at the end of each Tweet. Then:

```
tweetsdf <- fromJSON("india1_2019090713.json", simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)
```

`simplifyDataFrame` ensures the contents are saved as a data frame with one row per Tweet, and `flatten` collapses most of the nested [Tweet attributes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) to separate columns for each sub-value rather than generating columns full of unwieldy list structures.